# Is using "Says" in the beginning of a sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, writing-style, quotative-inversion

A listed company uses the following sentence structure in all its press releases:

> Says John Smith, Director, ABC Ltd, “The credit profiles of FMCG companies are likely to remain stable, supported by ...”

Is using "Says" at the beginning of a sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: "Yes." "No." "Says who?"

Comment: @nnnnnn you didn't even need that example. The OP have helpfully provided one of their own.

Comment: Also, questions normally use inversion, whereas the OP's example isn't a question.

Comment: It's arguably valid syntax.  Not idiomatic generally, but sometimes seen in things like press releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotative inversion is discussed in the style guide *The Right Word at the Right Time: A Guide to the English Language and How to Use It* (p301). It has this example:

> 'No, you cannot,' said Mrs Robinson.

It goes on to note:

> Certain modern writers...dislike this convention, and insist on
>   retaining the usual word order. ... This blanket objection seems
>   needlessly strict.
>
> In three specific cases, however, inversion should be avoided. First,
>   when the subject is a pronoun rather than a noun.
>
> - ?'No, you cannot,' said she.
>
> This now sounds laughably old-fashioned.
>
> The second case is all too modern, in the view of many purists; that
>   is, when the presentational material comes at the start of the
>   sentence:
>
> - ?Said Mrs Robinson: 'No, you cannot.'
>
> Associated with American news-magazines in particular, this rather
>   awkward structure is now fairly common in the journalism of Britain
>   and other English-speaking countries as well. Avoid using it unless
>   you are quite sure that it is in keeping with the style of the
>   publication or acceptable to your readers.

The third case in which inversion should be avoided according to the style guide is with 'more complex' verbs such as *admonished*.

The OP's sentence is a second-case example, and according to the style guide it is most often found in newspapers or magazines. The special language of newspapers is commonly called *journalese*. Further evidence for regarding this usage as journalese comes from *Social Stylistics: Syntactic Variation in British Newspapers*. The author cites a work by Crystal and Davey (*Investigating English Style*. 1969) which notes in the section on *journalese* that:

> Verbs of speaking, such as *say, declare or explain* are often
>   inverted with the subject as in *Said Dr Mason...* .

So, the usage is not ungrammatical but fairly rare and may momentarily distract the reader.

References:

Inversion - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English)

Quotative inversion: [Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1848)

[Social Stylistics: Syntactic variation in British Newspapers](https://books.google.de/books?redir_esc=y&id=zAy7sy08wL0C&q=journalese#v=snippet&q=journalese&f=false) (Google Books)

Comment: _All too modern_? Simple Simon says "No."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. And then there's the first line of the great King Crimson song _I talk to the wind_: '_Said the straight man to the late man_' - albeit a bit more modern that Simple Simon.

Comment: Reminds me of Nietzsche’s [*Thus spake Zarathustra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thus_Spoke_Zarathustra) and of Poe’s [*Quoth the Raven “Nevermore”*](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/48860/the-raven).

Comment: @tchrist. Yes, such usage works well in songs or poems (_The Raven quoth: 'Nevermore'_ doesn't have quite the same ring to it!). But it is on my (probably overlong) list of words or usages  in journalese that get up my nose.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [subject–verb inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English), and it's grammatically correct, although some forms are found more often than others. So both

> **Says** John Smith, "The credit profiles of ..."

and

> John Smith **says**, "The credit profiles of ..."

are idiomatic, although the second form is more likely to be found in speech. The first is a stylistic choice emphasising formality.

Comment: Specifically it is called [quotative inversion](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1848). The link is to a LanguageLog post by linguist Arnold Zwicky.

Comment: I've checked Google hits for "John Smith says" (45 000+) and ". Says John Smith" (0/100 relevant [verb-initial in sentence] hits in the first 100 hits). Idiomatic? I'd say stylistic, formal ... but rarefied. And sometimes quirky ('Said Simple Simon to the pieman, "Let me taste your ware." ')